# Azure Service Fabric: Make endpoint Input and Internal for identity server 4

Tags: azure-service-fabric, identityserver4

I want to run an application on Azure service fabric. One service should serve as identity provider. So I installed identity server 4 package on that 'usermanager'. I have also two other services which should use this usermanager for authentication and authorization.

That works on localhost. But on Azure I have the problem that an endpoint must be 'Input' or 'Internal' in my service manifest. But for my usermanager I need both input and internal.

```xml
    <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="IdentityServerEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="5000" />
```

/.well-known/openid-configuration needs 'Internal' and
/connect/authorize?xxxxxx  needs 'Input'

I found that for Input endpoints azure service fabric uses the full qualified domain name and for internal endpoints it uses the ip address of the lokal network like 10.0.0.4.

Is there a solution to make an endpoint both input and internal?
Or is there a solution to make identity server 4 to handle two endpoints?

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Believe it or not, the "Type" field in the Endpoint config doesn't actually do anything on any hosting platform. It's just metadata that you can configure and use in your code (basically a way for you to set your own policies). It doesn't matter what you put there otherwise.

Ultimately, you're opening an endpoint on a process on a VM. That endpoint will be open on the VM's IP and the port you choose, e.g., 10.0.0.1:5000.

If you want that endpoint to also be available on your cluster's VIP and FQDN, that configuration is external to Service Fabric. In Azure you just need to configure the Azure Load Balancer to forward external traffic on the port your service is listening on. See here for more info on that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services#connections-from-external-clients